# What is the word that functions as an object in a string of prepositions?

Tags: prepositions

I noticed someone asking about using three prepositions in a row. I have a question related to this, but I can't post it as a comment to the same post (not enough reputations :-().
In examples like: "He jumped out **from behind a dustbin**" or "come on **out from behind there to over here in front of me**", what is the object of each preposition? Can we say that for each preposition it is the following one (which can be a noun in other context)? Or do they share the same object?

Answer (score 3):

First, despite what a previous member said, "out" is seen as a prep in the latest grammars.

The 1st prep is "out". Its complement is the PP "from behind a dustbin".
The 2nd prep is "from". Its complement is the PP "behind a dustbin".
The 3rd prep is "behind". Its complement is the NP "a dustbin".

So we have a large PP "out from behind a dustbin" which contains the smaller PP "from behind a dustbin" which in turn contains the even smaller PP "behind a dustbin".

Complements of preps may be realised by several different types of dependent:

1. Object NP: "I was talking [to **a friend**]".
2. Predicative: "I regard her [as **a friend**]".
3. PP: "I stayed [until **after lunch**"].
4. AdvP: "It won't last [for **long**]".
5. Clause: "I left [**because I was tired**]".

Does that answer your question?

BillJ

Comment: _Because_ a preposition?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For you maybe a conjunctive preposition?!

Comment: Yes, I follow the latest thinking on the reclassification of words like "because" (and "provided", "though" "unless" etc.) that are traditionally seen as subordinators, as preps. It's too long a discussion for here right now, perhaps, but suffice to say that the reclassification makes for a far more cohesive syntax, as well as making the teaching of  subordinators vs adverbs vs  preps so much easier.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I'm not sure whether *out* is part of the same phrase as *from behind a dustbin* though.

Comment: I don't know if you're one of the people that I've pointed to counter-arguments to broadening the preposition class. eg with 'intransitive prepositions': 'We arrived at the lake earlier than we had expected, so we spent half an hour walking around' is markedly changed by adding a final 'it'.

Comment: ... Reason being "*From behind the dustbin, out jumped Bob*" or "*Out jumped Bob from behind the dustbin*". What d'you think?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a plausible answer except the "because" part!

Comment: @Nel Bill's right. "Because" is part of the same family of words like "after, in, before, like" etc. See the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* Huddleston and Pullum (2002)

Answer (score 1):

I will only look at the first example, because although prepositions are small words, they can be quite complicated! The second example: "*come on out from behind there to over here in front of me*" is every bit as complicated as a sentence with twelve clauses!

> He jumped out from behind a dustbin.

In many traditional grammars *out* would usually have been considered an adverb. Strange because most students would recognise it as a preposition until taught otherwise. In many, if not most, modern grammars it is indeed considered a preposition. So for the sake of keeping in with the Original Poster's question (and for the purposes of simplicity and sanity), I'll treat it as a preposition here.

So the preposition *out* here is a Complement of the verb *jumped*.

We might analyse *from behind a dustbin* as a separate Complement of the verb or as an Adjunct (or even possibly as a Complement of *out*, although I think this is unlikely).

Within the preposition phrase *from behind the dustbin*, the preposition *from* takes *behind the dustbin* as a Complement. Within *behind the dustbin* the preposition *behind* takes the noun phrase *a dustbin* as a Complement. We could construe the structure like this:

- He jumped [**PP** out] [**PP** from [**PP** behind [**NP** a dustbin]]]

... where PP stands for preposition phrase and NP stands for noun phrase.